# EF6 Migrations MVC5 Identity 2.1 - Multiplicity is not valid in Role

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I basically have a new MVC5/EF6 (individual user authentication) project and I'm trying to slightly modify the Identity Users table to include an Id for Country, State and City. I was able to create the new columns successfully through EF Migrations, but upon trying to add the FK constraints I hit a road block. I added a CountryId, StateId and CityId to the default Identity Users SQL table all set as a nullable Int value.

So, I have three similar classes for Country, State, City (State.cs shown):

```
public class State
    {
        [Key]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

I then have this extra chunk of code in my IdentityModels.cs ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("State")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("City")]
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual State State { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
// the rest is default....
}
```

Seems simple enough. However, it doesn't like me upon trying to add a migration:

```
PM> Add-Migration AddLocaleForeignKeys
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ApplicationUser_City_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_City_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_City'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ApplicationUser_Country_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Country_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Country'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ApplicationUser_State_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_State_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_State'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ApplicationUser_City_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_City_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_City'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ApplicationUser_Country_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Country_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Country'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
ApplicationUser_State_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_State_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_State'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

I've read some of the other similar issues here and I'm hoping someone can show me (in like mentally challenged terms) in my code what I'm doing wrong as I don't really get it from a terminology stand point (or looking at their code for that matter). I got my ideas for doing the FKs from basically dissected this link [HERE](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I'm also open to doing it other ways as I was considering doing a UserSettings table with all this info and then just do a FK contraint with UserId or something like that. However, this way seems like an extra unnecessary table to me.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating three one-to-one relationships and in this kind of relationship EF expects the two related tables share the same primary key values( the primary key of one table is also the PK and foreign key of the other), but I think this is not your case because a same `State` could be in several `ApplicationUsers`, so, you need to configure a one-to-many relationship instead.

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //...
    [ForeignKey("State")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

Do the same for `Country` and `City` entities.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work to eliminate the error at least. Although, that specific migration's public override void up and down are blank. So, no FKs will actually get added to the db... Also, I'm not sure I grasp this. A user will never have more than one country/state/city assigned to it and has the possibility to be null. So, to me it seems like a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship? The app won't ever be looking in the other direction, i.e. there won't ever be a point where I'm querying the State to show multiple users in it or listing multiple users in one state. Hmmmm, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is technically correct for my problem above. However, I found another answer I was looking for (mentioned above as well) which also solidified the reason I don't gamble.

In my last paragraph, I noted that I was open to doing it other ways... The following msdn blog describes exactly what I was referring too (having a separate user settings table linked by a single FK):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

I realize I can do it either way, but now that I'm looking at an error free model, etc. (thanks to octavioccl), trying to generate code for that from scratch will most certainly make my brain explode. I'm purely in a learning from examples only mode right now. Anyway, hopefully this answer might help someone else to save time and get over these learning hurdles.

Now, I'll have to see if I can melt my brain trying to undo all the EF migrations stuff and get back to where I started. Maybe I'll just start over... again...